# Using map on a Dictionary in Swift 2, to return a Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I'm having trouble figuring out Swift 2's particular style of `map`:

I'm reading in a dictionary (from a plist file), so I've got an `[String: AnyObject]`:

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject]
```

My goal is to transform from a dictionary of `Strings` into a dictionary of logger instances. This would be `[String: XCGLogger]`:

```
let loggers = dictionary
    .map { (n, l) in [ n: newLogger(l.0, withLevel: level(l.1)) ] }
```

However, this is returning an `[[String: XCGLogger]]` (which looks like an array of dictionaries to me). The question is how do I return a flattened dictionary. When I try to use `flatMap` I start running in circles around errors about closures or not being able to call flatMap on a type `(Key, Value) -> NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that `map` can return only arrays, and not dictionaries. To obtain a dictionary you have several strategies, for instance:

```
var loggers : [String: XCGLogger] = [:]
dictionary.map{(n, l) in loggers[n] = newLogger(l.0, withLevel: level(l.1))}
```

or perhaps:

```
var loggers : [String: XCGLogger] = [:]
for (n, l) in dictionary {
  loggers[n] = newLogger(l.0, withLevel: level(l.1))
}
```

loggers

Comment: The problem I have with this is that it's a non-functional approach, and being a Scala programmer first-and-foremost, it gives me shivers. Is there no way to return a `Dictionary` from map? I hate the idea of relying on a side effect to achieve my goal...! (I'd even opt for returning an array and then converting it to a dictionary...)

Comment: From the manual: "Map returns an Array containing the results of mapping transform over self". So it returns an Array, and cannot return a dictionary. I understand you being afraid about side-effects, but consider that Swift has a *very* good way of limiting them, with `var` and `let`, `struct` and `classes` and, moreover, that the basic frameworks requires side-effect, being written originally in C and Objective-C. So if you want to continue to program in Swift and iOS, I am afraid you have to take familiarity with non-functional programming techniques.

Comment: Understood – a shame though, I had hoped Swift 2 would be "more functional." Good strides though... definitely getting closer and closer with each iteration. I don't expect Swift to ever be purely functional, but I do like to see these features evolve.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct, and Swift2 is more and more functional. Nice thing!

Answer (score 5):

```
extension SequenceType {
  func toDict<K : Hashable, V>
    (@noescape convert: Generator.Element -> (K, V)) -> [K:V] {
    var result: [K:V] = [:]
    for x in self {
      let (key, val) = convert(x)
      result[key] = val
    }
    return result
  }
}

dictionary.toDict { (n, l) in (n, newLogger(l.0, withLevel: level(l.1))) }
```

Or

```
extension Dictionary {
  public init<
    S : SequenceType where
    S.Generator.Element == (Key, Value)
    >(_ seq: S) {
    self.init()
    for (k, v) in seq { self[k] = v }
  }
}

extension SequenceType {
  func toDict<K : Hashable, V>
    (@noescape convert: Generator.Element -> (K, V)) -> [K:V] {
    return Dictionary(lazy(self).map(convert))
  }
}

dictionary.toDict { (n, l) in (n, newLogger(l.0, withLevel: level(l.1))) }
```

Or

```
extension Dictionary {
  func map<K : Hashable, V>(@noescape transform: (Key, Value) -> (K, V)) -> [K:V] {
    var result: [K:V] = [:]
    for x in self {
      let (key, val) = transform(x)
      result[key] = val
    }
    return result
  }
}

dictionary
  .map { (n, l) in (n, newLogger(l.0, withLevel: level(l.1))) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more concise way from @Renzo's answer would be using reduce:

```
let loggers: [String: XCGLogger] = dictionary.reduce([:]){(var loggers, kv) in
loggers[kv.0] = newLogger(kv.1.0, withLevel: level(kv.1.1))
return loggers
}
```

It would be more convenient and clearer if Swift could destruct kv into (key, value). Hopefully future version of Swift, we will be able to do this.